# NoSuchMethodError when creating mapping for attachment type in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.elasticsearch.cn/tutorials/2011/07/18/attachment-type-in-action.html).

I start with installing attachment-mapper (replaced their link with latest version).

```
bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.4.1
```

Start new, delete "test" index and then create new one:

```
curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/test"
```

Create index, I presume:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test" -d '{
  "settings" : { "index" : { "number_of_shards" : 1, "number_of_replicas" : 0 }}
}'
```

Then I try to create mapping:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test/attachment/_mapping" -d '{
  "attachment" : {
    "properties" : {
      "file" : {
        "type" : "attachment",
        "fields" : {
          "title" : { "store" : "yes" },
          "file" : { "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets", "store":"yes" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then I get this error:

```
{
  "error" : "NoSuchMethodError[org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseMultiField(Lorg/elasticsearch/index/mapper/core/AbstractFieldMapper$Builder;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/elasticsearch/index/mapper/Mapper$TypeParser$ParserContext;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V]",
  "status" : 500
}
```

Any idea what's going on?
Could it be a problem with the attachment-mapper plugin installation?
attachment-mapper uses Tika. I've installed Tika, maybe that's installed wrong? How do I check?

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong version of ElasticSearch installed.

For the attachment-mapper plugin I had installed, I needed elasticsearch version 1.4.

Removed old version, installed new version, installed attachment-mapper plugin, started service, and ran through tutorial again and it worked.